# How to parallel transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

I wish to do the following past exam question:

> Given $2$-dim Euclidean space $\Bbb{E}_2$ with coordinates $(x^1,x^2) = (\rho,\phi)$ and $ds^2=d\rho^2 + k \rho^2 d\phi^2$.
>
> Prove that if a contravariant vector $a^i$ undergoes parallel transport around the circle $\rho=\rho_0$ from $\phi=0$ to $\phi=2\pi$, and $a^1=0, a^2=1$ at $\phi=0$, then at $\phi=2\pi$ we have:
> $$a^1 = \rho_0 k \sin(2\pi k),\qquad a^2=\cos(2\pi k)$$

So first I think that I have:
$$\frac{da^\lambda}{dt} = \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\,\,\,\lambda}  a^\mu \frac{dx^\nu}{dt}$$

and I have already worked out that $\Gamma_{12}^{\,\,\,2}=\frac{1}{\rho},\quad \Gamma_{22}^{\,\,\,1}=-\rho k^2,$

are the only non-vanishing symbols (with the symmetry for the first).

So we have that:
$$\dot{a}^1 = -\rho k^2 a^2 \dot{x}^2$$
$$\dot{a}^2 = \frac{1}{\rho}(a^1 \dot{x}^2 + a^2 \dot{x}^1),$$
but as specified we are staying at $\rho=\rho_0$, so $\dot{x}^1=0$ and hence:
$$\dot{a}^1 = -\rho k^2 a^2 \dot{x}^2$$
$$\dot{a}^2 = \frac{1}{\rho}(a^1 \dot{x}^2),$$
To solve this, must I first take $\phi(t)=2\pi t$ as a parametrization, so I can say $\dot{\phi}=2\pi$ so that:
$$\dot{a}^1 = -\rho k^2 a^2 2\pi$$
$$\dot{a}^2 = \frac{1}{\rho}(a^1 2\pi),$$
But this doesn't work, since I get solutions:
$a^2 = e^{2\pi ki}$ for example.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Feel free to transport it there, or I will transport it there shortly!

Comment: I'm uncertain of the notation "$(x^{1}, x^{2}) = (\rho, \phi)$": The left side presumably denotes Cartesian coordinates, the right side polar? On the other hand, if I'm reading right, the reasoning that "$\rho$ is constant, so $\dot{x}^{1} = 0$" suggests you're treating $x^{1} = \rho$ and $x^{2} = \phi$. Be that as it may, the geometric idea is that you're transporting around a sector of cone with vertex angle $2\pi k$. (If you have JSTOR access, [_Paper Surface Geometry_](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.06.487) may be of interest.)